# XOR-Encryption works on Code blocks not on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c, encryption, visual-studio-2017, xor

so I would like to encrypt my data when write into .txt file so I choose XOR-Encryption from this code:
[Github](https://github.com/KyleBanks/XOREncryption/blob/master/C/main.c)
So when I run in code blocks it runs and shows this result:

```
Encrypted: :=.43*-:8m2$.a
Decrypted:kylewbanks.com0

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.025 s
Press any key to continue.
```

But When I start use Visual Studio 2017 it shows this error:

```
Error (active)  E0059   function call is not allowed in a constant expression
```

Which means I cant put variable when declaring an array, so is there any method for my encryption to work in VS2017.
I think the problems is when declare the variable using constant, anyway to force it or other encryption method that is easy to use, I wont need to be secure just to prevent plain text in file.
 Anyway this is the only code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void encryptDecrypt(char *input, char *output) {
    char key[] = {'K', 'C', 'Q'}; //Can be any chars, and any size array

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))];
    }
}

int main () {
    char baseStr[] = "kylewbanks.com";

    char encrypted[strlen(baseStr)];
    encryptDecrypt(baseStr, encrypted);
    printf("Encrypted:%s\n", encrypted);

    char decrypted[strlen(baseStr)];
    encryptDecrypt(encrypted, decrypted);
    printf("Decrypted:%s\n", decrypted);
}
```

Comment: Source code?  My crystal ball is inoperative at the moment.

Comment: And what are you *doing* What does your code look like? Can you please provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: And there is problem with this encryption as well since the string above only shows "kylewbanks.com", but the decrypted data shows: "kylewbanks.com0", extra 0 in the end..

Comment: You need to reserve space for the trailing \0 e.g. ` char encrypted[strlen(baseStr) + 1];`, `char decrypted[strlen(baseStr)+1];` and you also need to place the trailing zero byte.

Comment: Remember that strings in C are really called *null **terminated** strings*. That termination means that a string of X characters need space for X+1 characters to fit the terminator. Without a terminator all standard string function will go out of bounds and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Note that if a character in the key ever encrypts the same character in the plain text, the output will be a null byte.  The encrypted material is not a string; it is an array of bytes with possible null bytes in the middle.  Therefore, you can't reliably print the encrypted data using `printf("Encrypted: %s\n", encrypted);` — you need to manage the binary data differently.  There are many possibilities; which is best depends on what you want to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSVC does not support Variable Length Arrays. One way round is to allocate the memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void encryptDecrypt(char *input, char *output) {
    char key[] = {'K', 'C', 'Q'}; //Can be any chars, and any size array
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))];
    }
    output[i] = '\0';               // terminate
}

int main () {
    char baseStr[] = "kylewbanks.com";
    size_t len = strlen(baseStr) + 1;

    char *encrypted = malloc(len);
    if(encrypted == NULL) {
        // error handling
    }
    encryptDecrypt(baseStr, encrypted);
    printf("Encrypted:%s\n", encrypted);

    char *decrypted = malloc(len);
    if(decrypted == NULL) {
        // error handling
    }
    encryptDecrypt(encrypted, decrypted);
    printf("Decrypted:%s\n", decrypted);

    free(decrypted);
    free(encrypted);
}
```

Please note that an extra byte is needed for the string terminator - and the string should be terminated.